# TPL How to Perform a 'Call-Back'

Tags: c#, multithreading, callback, task-parallel-library

I have a small application that needs to test SQL connection strings for a number of connections (each done one-at-a-time). To do this I set the `ConnectionTimeout = 5` temporarily to avoid a long wait if the connection is not valid and `ConnectionTimeout = 0` (wait forever), say.

To avoid the UI hanging whilst we attempt to `Open()` a bad connection (even with `ConnectionTimeout = 5` the wait for the `SqlException` can be up to twenty seconds), I want to run the test on a separate thread using Task Parallel Library (TPL). So I spin-off my new thread like:

```
Task<bool> asyncTestConn = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>
    (() => TestConnection(conn, bShowErrMsg));
return asyncTestConn.Result;
```

The problem is that this is still locking the UI (clearly), as it is waiting for the result before returning to the caller. How do I allow the code to return control to the UI (freeing up the GUI) whilst getting the eventual result from the asynchronous `Task`?

Also, from within a `Task` can I legitimately do `MessageBox.Show("Some message")`? This does not work for `BackgroundWorkers` and this pooled-thread is a background thread by default; yet it does not seem to be a problem. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, this is where the waiting happens:

```
 return asyncTestConn.Result;
```

You could simply build the finish-up code in the tail of TestConnection() or use a Continuation:

```
// untested
//Task<bool> asyncTestConn = Task.Factory.Create<bool> (
Task<bool> asyncTestConn = new Task<bool> (
    () => TestConnection(conn, bShowErrMsg));
asyncTestConn.ContinueWith(MyFinishCode);
asyncTestConn.Start()
```

> can I legitimately do `MessageBox.Show("Some message")`?

Actually Yes, the MessageBox is thread-safe. Should be possible from a Bgw as well.

But you are prolonging the life of the Task by a lot, it's not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. The whole idea is to get back to pass control back to the UI/GUI as soon as possible, how does/can the above achieve that? If I am calling the above code from a method called `ParrTestConn(SqlConnection conn, string bShowErrMsg)` then I can't say `asyncTestConn.ContinueWith(ParrTestConn(conn, bShowErrMsg))`... Or can I?

Comment: @Killer You can simply return after the Start(). The GUI should stay responsive when using this.

Comment: I do not have the `Task.Factory.Create<T>` method avilible?

Answer (score 5):

For the TPL, `ContinueWith` is exactly what you want. Expanding on Henk's answer:

```
var asyncTestConn = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => TestConnection(conn, bShowErrMsg));
// Henk's "MyFinishCode" takes a parameter representing the completed
// or faulted connection-testing task.
// Anything that depended on your "return asyncTestConn.Result;" statement
// needs to move into the callback method.
asyncTestConn.ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        switch (task.Status)
        {
            // Handle any exceptions to prevent UnobservedTaskException.
            case TaskStatus.Faulted: /* Error-handling logic */ break;
            case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion: /* Use task.Result here */ break;
        }
    },
    // Using this TaskScheduler schedules the callback to run on the UI thread.
    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: Really helpful. Thanks. The combination of the two answers is absolutely mint.